# Name for a monoid on the basis of a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, semigroups-and-monoids, vector-spaces

Is there a name for the structure of a vector space with a monoid defined on its basis?

Given a vector space V over a field F, we can choose a basis and define a monoid on it. Now we can use each basis vector as an operator on the vector space by doing monoid addition on each term in the decomposition.

I feel a structure like this would have many applications. For example, if we take the Talor Series basis for the analytic function and define the monoid of the natural numbers under addition on it, we can get a different operator. I also believe this structure could be used to represent problems in computability theory.

I am new to algebra so I was wondering if this was a real thing or not? Is there a name for vector spaces with particular algebras defined on their basis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This construction is known as the monoid algebra (especially group algebras are important).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring